# INSERT INTO a table created dynamically SELECT * FROM a table variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

Here is the code of the stored procedure

1. I declare a Table variable @Test
2. I insert data in the @Test table variable
3. I dynamically create a table `@TableName` that the name include the date and time
4. I want to insert all the data from the `@Test` table variable into the `@TableName` table variable

My code:

```
-- Declare variables to create a table dynamically
    @TableName varchar(100),
    @DateFormat varchar(14) = 'yyyyMMddHHmmss',
    @DateValue varchar(14) = '',    
    @PrefixTableName VARCHAR(MAX) = 'MCTest_',
    @sql_create VARCHAR(max),
    @sql_insert VARCHAR(max)


BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @Test TABLE (field1 VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
                         field2 VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
                         field3 VARCHAR(max) NULL,
                         field4 VARCHAR(max) NULL)
    
    INSERT INTO @Test 
        SELECT 'aaa', '4', 'cccc', 'ddd'

    SET @DateValue =  (SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), @DateFormat))

    SET @TableName = @PrefixTableName + @DateValue

    --SELECT @DateValue, @TableName

    SET @sql_create=
        '   CREATE TABLE ' + @TableName + 
        '   (field1 VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
            field2 VARCHAR(max) NULL,
            field3 VARCHAR(max) NULL,
            field4 VARCHAR(max) NULL)'
    
    --execute the query contained inside the variable
    EXEC (@sql_create)
    
    SET @sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TableName +  ' SELECT * FROM @Test ' 
        
    PRINT @sql_insert;
    EXEC (@sql_insert);
END TRY
```

When I executed the stored procedure I got this error:

> Error Message: Must declare the table variable "@Test"

I will enjoy if you can help me.

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 1):

```
you can use temporary table(#Test) instead of table variable(@Test).


@TableName varchar(100),
    @DateFormat varchar(14) = 'yyyyMMddHHmmss',
    @DateValue varchar(14) = '',    
    @PrefixTableName VARCHAR(MAX) = 'MCTest_',
    @sql_create VARCHAR(max),
    @sql_insert VARCHAR(max)

BEGIN TRY
 
    create TABLE #Test  (field1 VARCHAR(max) NULL, field2 VARCHAR(max) NULL, field3 VARCHAR(max) NULL,
                         field4 VARCHAR(max) NULL)
    
    INSERT INTO #Test select 'aaa','4','cccc','ddd'

    SET @DateValue =  (SELECT format(getdate(),@DateFormat))

    SET @TableName = @PrefixTableName + @DateValue

    --SELECT @DateValue, @TableName

    set @sql_create=
        '   CREATE TABLE ' + @TableName + 
        '   (field1 VARCHAR(max) NULL, 
            field2 VARCHAR(max) NULL,
            field3 VARCHAR(max) NULL,
            field4 VARCHAR(max) NULL)'
    
    --execute the query contained inside the variable
    exec (@sql_create)
    
    SET @sql_insert = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TableName +  ' SELECT * FROM #Test ' 
       
    PRINT @sql_insert;
    exec (@sql_insert);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. It solves my problem.

Comment: I wanted to know what is the difference between @Test and #Test?
When when we have to use @Test? and when we have to use #Test?

Answer (score 0):

Exec is not operating in the same transaction scope as the rest of the query.  In order to do it the way you are trying, you would need to create a globally scoped temp table ##test or an actual table and insert the data into that, before selecting the data back out of it.

```
CREATE TABLE ##test (field1 VARCHAR(max) NULL, field2 VARCHAR(max) NULL, field3 VARCHAR(max) NULL,
                         field4 VARCHAR(max) NULL)

INSERT INTO ##Test select 'aaa','4','cccc','ddd'


select * from ##test


exec('select * from ##test')
```